Thermal Cutoff Help


I'm working on an Electric Ryobi Mower.  The motor shuts off a few minutes after mowing.  It appears that the Thermal Cutoff is bad.  I've searched everywhere over the past 2 months and can't find a replacement.  I've attached a photo of the motor specs and the thermal cutoff.
Thermal Cutoff Specs: 17 AM-D / 120 Z / +PTC 

Please post a picture and dimensions of the fuse

Hi, I hope my edit meets the site's standards.

This appears to be a 120'C N.C. thermal cutoff with self-hold (power interruption and cooling required to reset). It's a safety device so there is risk associated with replacing the part with other than the manufacturer's exact recommended spare part, though similar items are on offer.

There may as well be a motor or air convection issue. Did you test the cutoff temperature of this device? It is possible, that it just does, what it is made for.

Why do you think that the cutoff is bad? It may be bad, it may not be. Its whole function is to turn the motor off. If it does turn the motor off, it may be working just fine, and the problem is with the motor. Measure the motor temperature at the point where the cutoff was installed. You can also test the cutoff by putting it into a water-tight ziploc baggie and carefully lowering it into boiling water. It should not turn off. If it indeed stays on at 100C, then it is most likely perfectly fine and does its job of not letting the mower motor burn out. How long have you been using the mower?
